# Strange sound error in my ActionScript3 game

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

Sometimes I get this strange error during gameplay:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at com.efg.framework_mod::SoundManager/playSound()[/Users/xxx/Documents/Developer/AS3_Flex/game_development/projects/xxx/SpaceGame/libs/src/com/efg/framework_mod/SoundManager.as:106]
at com.xxx.games.spacegame::Main/soundEventListener()[/Users/xxx/Documents/Developer/AS3_Flex/game_development/projects/xxx/SpaceGame/src/com/xxx/games/spacegame/Main.as:1407]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.xxx.games.spacegame::SpaceGame/createEnemyProj()[/Users/xxx/Documents/Developer/AS3_Flex/game_development/projects/xxx/SpaceGame/src/com/xxx/games/spacegame/SpaceGame.as:3708]
```

I still don't know what causes the error. The only thing I discovered is that sometimes an object is null inside of my SoundManager. But I don't know why. I already checked all appropriate arrays if something's missing there but all seems to be ok there.

This is the part of the SoundManager where the error occurs:

```
public function playSound(soundName:String, isSoundTrack:Boolean = false, loops:int = 1, offset:Number = 0, _volume:Number = 1, fadeIn:Boolean = false,
                                _duration:Number = 1):void {



    tempSoundTransform.volume = _volume;


    tempSound = sounds[soundName];//sometimes null (still don't know why)

    if (!fadeIn) {
        if (isSoundTrack) {
            if (soundTrackChannel != null) {
                soundTrackChannel.stop();
            }
            soundTrackChannel = tempSound.play(offset, loops);                              
            soundTrackChannel.soundTransform = tempSoundTransform;  
        } else {


            soundChannels[soundName] = tempSound.play(offset, loops);//sometimes null but still don't know why

            soundChannels[soundName].soundTransform = tempSoundTransform;//line 106 (see errors above)


        }
    } else {

        fadeInSoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0, 0);

        if (isSoundTrack) {
            if (soundTrackChannel != null) {
                soundTrackChannel.stop();
            }
            soundTrackChannel = tempSound.play(offset, loops, fadeInSoundTransform);
        } else {
            soundChannels[soundName] = tempSound.play(offset, loops, fadeInSoundTransform);

        }

        TweenLite.to(fadeInSoundTransform, _duration, {volume:_volume, onUpdate:updateFadeIn, onUpdateParams:[soundName, isSoundTrack]});
    }
}
```

This is line 3708 (see errors above):

```
dispatchEvent(new CustomEventSound(CustomEventSound.PLAY_SOUND, enemyProjSounds[tempEnemyProj._type], false, 0, 8, setSoundVolume, false, false, 0));
```

This is the class CustomEventSound:

```
public function CustomEventSound(type:String, name:String, isSoundTrack:Boolean = false, loops:int = 0,
            offset:Number = 0, _volume:Number = 1, fadeIn:Boolean = false, fadeOut:Boolean = false,
        _duration:Number = 2, startVol:Number = 1, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
{
    super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    this.name = name;
    this.loops = loops;
    this.offset = offset;
    this._volume = _volume;
    this.isSoundTrack = isSoundTrack;
    this.fadeIn = fadeIn;
    this.fadeOut = fadeOut;
    this._duration = _duration;
    this.startVol = startVol;

}

public override function clone():Event {
    return new CustomEventSound(type, name, isSoundTrack, loops, offset, _volume, fadeIn, fadeOut, _duration, startVol, bubbles, cancelable)
}


public override function toString():String {
    return formatToString(type, "type", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase", name, isSoundTrack, loops, offset, _volume, fadeIn,
                fadeOut, _duration, startVol);
}
```

The Listener-function for CustomEventSounds-Events

```
override public function soundEventListener(e:CustomEventSound):void {

if (e.type == CustomEventSound.PLAY_SOUND) {

soundManager.playSound(e.name, e.isSoundTrack, e.loops, e.offset, e._volume, e.fadeIn, e._duration);
} else {
    soundManager.stopSound(e.name, e.isSoundTrack, e.fadeOut, e._duration, e.startVol);
}
}
```

Comment: um what is at SoundManager.as:106

Comment: soundChannels[soundName].soundTransform = tempSoundTransform;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a maximum of 32 active sound channels at a time. When you call `tempSound.play(offset, loops)` it will return `null` when there are already 32 sounds currently playing.

So you should keep track of the number of sounds playing, and `stop()` the oldest `SoundChannel` when you have 32 and a new sound must be played, or just ignore the new sound if `Sound.play()` returns `null`.

Comment: Wow! This is something that I didn't know so far. Thank you very much!:) I will try this asap...

Comment: Found a possible solution: [link]http://blog.curiousmedia.com/?q=blog/flash-player-can-only-play-32-sounds-time

Still testing the game so far I can't see any errors any more...